# Any kind of connectors for these switches?

Tags: switches, connector, wiring

I've got these toggle switches - each of the legs are around 1.2mm wide.

Are there any connectors for these legs - e.g. spade...but haven't seen anything 1.2mm wide.

I'd prefer not to solder it.

[ebay switch](https://www.ebay.com/itm/301413640867?hash=item462da72aa3:g:pwcAAOSwVbVfFxL9)

Comment: There are not. You could try wire wrapping them if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name implies, they are PCB mount switches, so those legs are designed to go into through-holes on a PCB.  You could try using contacts for a rectangular connector of similar size but the crimp tool will almost certainly be prohibitively expensive and, of course, the retention strength will not be guaranteed.  It's possible to get switches with a pre-wired harness attached - usually 6" or 12" - screw terminals, or quick disconnect terminals from places such as Digikey or Mouser and the prices compare favorably to what you might find on ebay.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the title, they are intended for PCB mounting. There is no connector designed to mate with those pins, and it is unlikely that the current rating could be preserved even if there was something that would fit.